# Return <Promise> from get in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm taking my first steps with react and I'm trying to make a get request  with data that I get in app i pass it to other component.
The problem is that i get this:

```
[undefined, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]
```

What is wrong?

Here is my code:

APP.JS

```
    const elements1 = await axios.get(axios.defaults.baseURL)
      // this works ok.

     const Allelements = await Promise.all(elements1.data.elements.map(element => { 

          if(element.type == 'CONTENT'){
            const contentType = responseElements.data.elements.map(element => element)
            this.setState({content : contentType})
          }
}))
```

HERE I SEND THE STATE to home:

```
 <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <Home {...props} content={this.state.content} />}/> // this send the data ok.
```

HOME receives IT and pass it, and work ok:

```
<ContentGroupTall content={this.props.content}>
```

CONTENTGROUPTALL.JS --> HERE is the problem.

```
 componentDidUpdate(){

     const a = this.props.content // a have the data

    const b = a.map(element => element.content).filter(element => element != null)

    const c = b.map(element => { 
      if(element.type == 'RAIL'){
      return axios.get(`http://url:3000/${element.id}`)
      }
    })
    console.log('cccccccc', c) --> [undefined, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]
```

Comment: If there is no return in a `map` then undefined gets returned. Your issue is when you check the element type (aka `if (element.type == 'RAIL')`) you dont have an else statement where you can put another type of request in that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.get` returns a Promise, so you map an array to promises, except the first case, when `element.type` probably doesn't equal `RAIL`.

You can filter them out first, then resolve it with `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(
   b.filter(element => element.type === 'RAIL')
    .map(element => axios.get(`http://url:3000/${element.id}`))
)
.then(res => res.forEach(element => console.log(element)));
```

You can also use destructuring to avoid verbosity:

```
Promise.all(
    b.filter(({type}) => type === 'RAIL')
     .map(({id}) => axios.get(`http://url:3000/${id}`))
)
.then(res => res.forEach(element => console.log(element)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that i get a lot of : Promise {<pending>} Promise {<pending>} Promise {<pending>} Promise {<pending>} :(

Comment: Sorry, I forget the resolving, give a try now please.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your c array with Promise.all. Then you can continue with the resolved promises in a then statement after Promise.all to get the values.